# Selecting date range MySQL with date_format

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

I've got an issue selecting a date range with MySQL.

```
SELECT MvtDate,date_format(MvtDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
  FROM (`immmvt`)
 WHERE date_format(MvtDate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN '01-01-2010' AND '02-01-2010'
```

`mvtDate` type is date like `2010-01-01 00:00:00`.

When I run the query, the result works for the days and the months but it also show me other result from other years.

Like `01-01-2011` etc.

Comment: Comparision of dates of `DATE` time is better compared to what you're trying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `STR_TO_DATE` since you want to convert `string` back to `date`

```
SELECT MvtDate, date_format(MvtDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
FROM  `immmvt`
WHERE MvtDate BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-01-2010','%d-%m-%Y') AND 
                      STR_TO_DATE('02-01-2010','%d-%m-%Y')
```

```
FYI: DATE_FORMAT() converts date to formatted string representation.
     STR_TO_DATE() converts formatted string back to date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MvtDate,date_format(MvtDate,'%d-%m-%Y')
  FROM (`immmvt`)
 WHERE date_format(MvtDate,'%d-%m-%Y') IN ('01-01-2010', '02-01-2010')
```

Comment: well this is the best answer I found which is very quick.