# How to verify if day and month of date are in a range using SQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, validation, date-range

This is an algorithm to check if within the **previous or next 2 weeks** was/gonna be the birthday of some user and if yes, it shows the user and the date of his birthday.
The fetch arrays do work, returning day and month, but the SQL does not return a thing.

**BornDate** is a date field, so there is no need to use str_to_date (I tried that).
I tried to remove the function str_to_date applied on next two variables: got no result either. What am I doing wrong? There isn't any easier way to achieve what I need? My code:

```
$sub = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select date_sub(curdate(), interval 14 day);"));
$before = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select date_format('$sub[0]', '%d-%m');"));

$add = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select date_add(curdate(), interval 14 day);"));
$after = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select date_format('$add[0]', '%d-%m');"));

$sql = "select * from user where date_format(bornDate, '%d-%m') between str_to_date('$before[0]', '%d-%m') and str_to_date('$after[0]', '%d-%m');";
$request = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) != 0) {
  while ($user = mysqli_fetch_array($request, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $user['name'];
    echo $user['bornDate'] . "<br>";
  }
} else {
  echo "No user does/did birthday on previous/next 2 weeks";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a date is in a given range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976669/how-to-check-if-a-date-is-in-a-given-range)

Comment: Or maybe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910691/selecting-date-range-mysql-with-date-format

Comment: I think he asked how to reduce query code? Instead of getting the start and end date through SQL query get it through PHP date function and then directly go for a single query.

Comment: No, friend. These questions are about a full date range. I need to check if a day and a month of a SQL field are within a range. I cant do that using the year.

Comment: @GuilhermyCamargo  Also if you are trying to compare today's' date then previous 2 weeks is un-understandable to me

Comment: @AlivetoDie This algorithm must verify if the users' birthday was in previous 2 weeks, or if it will be in next two weeks, by taking the current date. Got it?

Comment: @Cœur You can see in the comments that wasn't me whom found the solution. And I marked the comment as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the SQL code to:

```
$sql = "select * from user where DAYOFYEAR(bornDate) between DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-13 and DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+15;";
```

All fetch arrays above the $sql are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this query  to get  the result (user born within previous or next 2 weeks)

```
select * from user where DAYOFYEAR(bornDate) between 
DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-14 and DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+14
```

Comment: This does not work. BornDate contains dates like 1998-05-09. CURDATE uses the current year too. Only if the user has born within 14 days he will be listed.

Comment: I have modified my answer. Please try and use this

Comment: Actually, I have tried some dates. If the birthday is March 4 (or less), it is not listed. If the birthday is March 5 (or more), it is listed. Now trying future dates: If the birthday is May 8 (or less), it is listed. If the birthday is May 9 (or more) it is not listed.

Comment: @Guilhermy try this query

Comment: Alright. I just tried your new query. Seems to work, but it is listing March 15 birthdays (2 weeks and 1 day previous), and it is not listing May 13 birthdays (exactly 2 weeks next).

Comment: This probably  is the nearest  i can get you with this query. You may need to tinker with it  for more accuracy

Comment: some tinkering like this DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-13 and DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())+15 etc

Comment: Yeah! This actually works just fine! You have solved my problem. Thanks a lot. (I am talking about the query -13/+15)

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
WHERE date_format(bornDate, '%m-%d') between '07-01' and '10-01'
```

Comment: I just tried using this range, and I got no result. But I changed '07-01' to '01-01' and '10-01' to '31-12'. All users were listed. See that my code uses the mask day-month.

Comment: WHERE 
(date_format(bornDate, '%m-%d') between '12-20' and '12-31') OR 
(date_format(bornDate, '%m-%d') between '01-01' and '01-05')

Comment: This works on predefined dates. This code must check and update dates every day.